# How to isolate handleSubmit() functions in React Hooks Form when the forms are nested such that they don't trigger each other?

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, react-hook-form

I am using [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for forms in my **Next JS App**. I have two forms `FormA` & `FormB` components. But the issue is whenever I execute the `handleSubmit()` function for child `FormB`, the `handleSubmit()` function for parent `FormA` also gets executed.

```
<FormA onSubmit(handleSubmit(submitFunctionA)>
   ............
  <FormB onSubmit(handleSubmit(submitFunctionB))>
  </FormB>
   ............
</FormA>
```

After applying suggestions from comments. My issue is fixed as shown below.

```
                <form
                    onSubmit={(event) => {
                 //Child Form's onSubmit function here//
                      handleSubmit(onSubmit)(event);

                      if (event) {
                        if (typeof event.preventDefault === "function") {
                          event.preventDefault();
                        }
                        if (typeof event.stopPropagation === "function") {
                          event.stopPropagation();
                        }

                      }
                    }}
                  >
```

Comment: You probably need to add a default event prevention and stop the propagation of the submit event upstream from `FormB` (i.e. `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events get propagated up the tree to their parents, so this behaviour is normal. In order to stop the propagation, try adding this to your child handleSubmit:

```
    if (event) {
      if (typeof event.preventDefault === 'function') {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      if (typeof event.stopPropagation === 'function') {
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are all the checks necessary ? Can't you just execute the functions ?

Comment: It's just to be on the safe-side and avoid edge cases.